# How to get the windows time in vc++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to find out how to get the date (day of week; day of month with 1st, 2nd, etc; month; and year). In Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express, the underlined section of the following code gets the error:
int tm::tm wday
Error: a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific oject

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
int main () 
{
int a;
a = tm.tm_wday;
}
```

"a = tm::tm_wday;"
 gets the same error.

Please help me remove this error.

Comment: When you say `tm.tm_wday`, you are accessing a class/struct member `tm_wday` with object `tm`. But, what is `tm` in the program ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tm is a struct. You need to create an object to access it's member.

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/localtime/ for an example

Answer (score 2):

Normally you do something like this:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() { 
    static const char *names[] = { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"};

    time_t current = time(NULL);
    struct tm *now = localtime(&current);

    std::cout << names[now->tm_wday];
    return 0;
}
```

As it stands right now, this just prints an abbreviation for the current day of the week, but (of course) once you've initialized a `struct tm` with the correct data, you can use all the fields from it that you want.

Note, however, that `localtime` returns the address of a statically allocated buffer. Calling any other time function can overwrite that buffer, so if you need the data for any length of time you generally want to define a `struct tm` to store it, and copy the data from the buffer used by `localtime` into your own buffer.

Also note that instead of defining your own array of the names of days of the week, you usually want to use `strftime` to format output. It not only has those (and names of months, etc.) built in already, but can also (at least if memory serves) localize the names based on the locale.